# How to test if a number is Negative Zero (-0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to test if the result of an operation (or a number) is Negative Zero (-0).

Doing a comparison using `==` or `===` does not work because:

```
0  == -0     // true
0 === -0     // true
```

I have considered that a number divided by -0 will give -Infinity; so if say 1 is divided by the number to be tested results in `-Infinity`, then the input number was `-0`.

```
1/number == -Infinity;   // true if number is -0
```

Is this a valid and sound/correct method to do the test; or is there an alternative better way for testing?

Also, is there any other number (other than -0) if `1 / number` will also give -Infinity? Therefore the necessity for testing first that the number is zero before the check is made that it is -0. i.e. as follows:

```
number ==0 && 1/number == -Infinity;
```

Thanks

```js
function isMinusZero(number) {return 1/number == -Infinity;}


// ========= Test Cases ===================
console.log(isMinusZero(-0))              // TRUE
console.log(isMinusZero(-0-0));           // TRUE
console.log(isMinusZero("-0"));           // TRUE
console.log(isMinusZero(55/-Infinity));   // TRUE (Number divided by -Infinity is -0)

console.log("--------------");

console.log(isMinusZero(0));              // FALSE
console.log(isMinusZero("0"));            // FALSE
console.log(isMinusZero(4));              // FALSE
console.log(isMinusZero(-Infinity));      // FALSE
```

Answer (score 7):

`Object.is` will give you what you want:

```js
const theNum = -0;

console.log(Object.is(theNum, -0));
console.log(Object.is(0, -0));
```

Answer (score -3):

Try giving -0 as string

```
'0'  == '-0'
```

Comment: `String(-0) === "0"`. Negative 0 is a distinct number, not a string.